# ActionScript3 'Worker' does not work so well

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to decrypt an encrypted video in my opne-source project SparrowPlayer(https://github.com/yatsen-yang/SparrowPlayer),and I found that decrypting the video may block the main thread for several seconds.It resulted in stopping renderring UI assets on the stage, which is unacceptable.So I think 'Worker' may do some help. I followed the example code of the online API about Worker(http://help.adobe.com/zh_CN/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.htm l). I tested and it worked well.

But I found that if I embed the BGWorker.swf in other class like com.xx.Test instead of in the document class, 'Worker' did not work so well.Sometimes main worker could not communicate with bgworker even that the state of bgworker is running.
The example code followed:

```
private function handleBGWorkerStateChange(event:Event):void
{
      if (bgWorker.state == WorkerState.RUNNING)
      {
              _statusText.text = "Background worker started";
             bgWorkerCommandChannel.send(["startCount", 100000000]);
      }
```

}

It happened sometimes, not every time. If main worker send a message after 1 second when listening that the state of bgworker is running, the code works well

So it confused me. Logically, if the state of bgworker is running, it should mean that main worker can communicate with bgworker, and it works well if you embed the bgworker swf in the document class.But if you embed the bgworker swf in other class, you will have problem sometime.

Finally, I found a solution.I embed the bgworker swf in other class instead of in the document class, and when bgworker initializes successfully, it send a message to main worker.Main worker communicates withe bgworker immediately if it  receives the message coming from bgworker. Now the problem is solved.

I want to know why the state of Worker not reliable when I embed the bgworker swf in other class.Is it a bug of Worker?

Answer (score 1):

It's been 2 years since the question was asked, but for anyone who has a similar problem, it's because the RUNNING state simply indicates that the constructor has started. It may not have finished executing it; therefore, a workaround is to send a "finish startup" message from the worker SWF.

> You may be tempted to use the built-in WorkerState events to synchronize your thread startup. It’s very appealing to avoid the extra steps you see above by simply listening for the WorkerState.RUNNING event like so:
>
> Do not be fooled! The RUNNING state only means that the Worker has been created and begun executing its constructor. It may or may not have finished its constructor, so you will most likely get intermittent problems due to the worker thread not having finished setting itself up. A “startup” MessageChannel avoids this possibility and ensures a smooth thread startup.

From https://jacksondunstan.com/articles/2401

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar with the SparrowPlayer and Worker API. But it looks like it is the problem if initialization. It will fail when your class is not initialized when it is being called.

When you move it to a separate class and on initialization you send a message to worker.main class, it works because your worker is being initiated every single time which guarantees its initialization before it is called.

One way of initializing display objects/elements is to set the CreationPolicy to All in your main Application.